# How to distinguish between XSSF and HSSF automatically in Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to be able to open Excel file of arbotrary type. Is it possible to select between [`HSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) and [`XSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) automatically?

Currently I write

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
```

Can I write universal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! All you need to do is use [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html)

As per [this part of the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), it's better to use a `File` than an `InputStream`. So, just do something like:

```
File file = new File("input.xls");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

That will create whichever of `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook` your file needs